# Постоянно банит фейсбук

Tags: facebook

Фейсбук постоянно банит личный аккаунт (создаю новый банит), аккаунт настоящий не левый. А к аккаунту создается "бизнес страница", для рекламы. Реклама модерируется-принимается и запускается (запрещеннего соответственно нет, так как модерация ручная). Через пол месяца, просят прислать фото для подтверждения аккаунта, отсылаю и через пару дней БАН (без пояснения).

Я так подозреваю, что раньше у меня были левые аккаунты (их забанили) и теперь алгоритм Фейсбук видит мой комп (электронное имя компа..... наверное это так звучит) и банит все новые аккаунты. Потому как, когда создаю новый аккаунт, я его создаю на других компах (компах знакомых) но затем приходится работать на своем компе, и при сканировании меня вычисляют.

Подскажите решение этой проблемы. Я так понимаю нужно сменить системник и лучше пользоваться хорошим VPN (на всяк случай).

Подскажите умный совет.

Comment: Насколько я помню - для бизнес-страницы не нужно создавать новый аккаунт, а достаточно создать страницу из существующего.

Answer (score 1):

Если они тебя реально заблочили, то попробуй затестить у друга дома на его железе или ноуте. Просто прикинуть методом исключения, либо воспользоваться VPN и так же затестить.
https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/260749603972907 ссылка поддержки,
когда ты создаёшь много аккаунтов они начинают их так же блокировать, не использовать каких-либо слов, потому что придераются жёстко .